# pip install "mahotas" causing error in android chaquopy

Tags: python, android, android-studio, pip, chaquopy

I've been trying to use chaquopy to run my python script in Android studio. But I've been having a trouble in pip install part in build.gradle. But numpy, pandas and opencv-python were installed successfully.

```
    python{
        pip{
            install "mahotas"
        }
    }
```

The synchronization is done without any errors. But when I run the app, following errors are occurred.

CCompiler.compile:Chaquopy cannot compile native code and
Failed to install mahotas from http://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/....

As I see during the gradle build running, other libraries like numpy have .whl extension and mahotas has .tar.gz extension.

Comment: Mahotas isn't available for Chaquopy yet. To be notified if we add it in the future, please subscribe to the [existing entry](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/373) on our issue tracker.